# Storing shapes in JavaScript array to redraw after some operation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am developing an editor in html5. I have buttons for creating shapes when clicked, including triangle, rectangle, hexa, penta, heptagons, lines, and so on. Now I also want to perform operations on these shapes such as rotate, flip, undo, redo, ...etc. I want to save these drawn objects in a JavaScript array or something so I can create them after performing operations on the canvas, since individual shapes cannot be rotated or flipped in canvas, we have to redraw it. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a project where if you click on an image of a rectangle you can then draw a rectangle, click on an ellipse then you can draw an ellipse. My shapes are stored as objects which are then drawn using Canvas and can be flipped, rotated etc I have not implemented undo redo.

My project is at http://canvimation.github.com/

The source code for my project is at https://github.com/canvimation/canvimation.github.com

The master branch is the current working code. You are welcome to use any of the code or fork the project.

Answer (score 0):

as you said, you have to clear your context and redraw your shapes any time you change them.
It's not mandatory to clear and redraw all the context, you can just redraw the region in which a shape is modified.

So you have to think your shapes as objects (in a OOP way) with their own properties and render method.
What I'd do is to create another class to apply transformations to a shape (a flip is just a -1 scale).

If you go this way, it could become a huge work (the more features you add, the more complexe your code becomes and the first design of your application may be re-think during the work).
What I can suggest to you is to use a framework that already does the job.

For example, [cgSceneGraph](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/) is designed to let developers add their own rendering method and provides a lot of methods to manipulate them. I'm the designer of the framework, feel free to ask more on about how to apply transformations or create your own nodes (tutorials and examples are already on the website, but I'll please to help you).

Comment: Thanks for for your help and suggestion sir, i will look forward to it and will definitely ask you if i got stuck anywhere. Thanks again.